# Multiply various subsets of a data frame by different elements of a vector R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(id=rep(1:10,each=10),
               Room1=rnorm(100,0.4,0.5),
               Room2=rnorm(100,0.3,0.5),
               Room3=rnorm(100,0.7,0.5))
```

And a vector:

```
vals <- sample(7:100, 10)
```

I want to multiply cols Room1, Room2 and Room3 by a different element of the vector for every unique ID number and output a new data frame (df2).

I managed to multiply each column per id by EVERY element of the vector using the following:

```
samp_func <- function(x) {
  x*vals[i]
}

for (i in vals) {
  df2 <- df %>% mutate_at(c("Room1", "Room2", "Room3"), samp_func)
}
```

But the resulting df (df2) is each Room column multiplied by the same element of the vector (vals) for each of the different ids. When what I want is each Room column (per id) multiplied by a different element of the vector vals. Sorry in advance if this is not clear I am a beginner and still getting to grips with the terminology.

Thanks!

EDIT: The desired output should look like the below, where the columns for each ID have been multiplied by a different element of the vector *vals*.

```
   id         Room1       Room2        Room3
1   1  24.674826880  60.1942571  46.81276141
2   1  21.970270107  46.0461779  35.09928150
3   1  26.282357614  -3.5098880  38.68400541
4   1  29.614182061 -39.3025587  25.09146592
5   1  33.030886472  46.0354881  42.68209027
6   1  41.362699668 -23.6624632  26.93845129
7   1   5.429031042  26.7657577  37.49086963
8   1  18.733422977 -42.0620572  23.48992138
9   1 -17.144070723   9.9627315  55.43999326
10  1  45.392182468  20.3959968 -16.52166621
11  2  30.687978299 -11.7194020  27.67351631
12  2  -4.559185345  94.9256561   9.26738357
13  2  86.165076849  -1.2821515  29.36949423
14  2 -12.546711562  47.1763755 152.67588456
15  2  18.285856423  60.5679496 113.85971720
16  2  72.074929648  47.6509398 139.69051486
17  2 -12.332519694  67.8890324  20.73189965
18  2  80.889634991  69.5703581  98.84404415
19  2  87.991093995 -20.7918559 106.13610773
20  2  -2.685594148  71.0611693  47.40278949
21  3   4.764445589  -7.6155681  12.56546664
22  3  -1.293867841  -1.1092243  13.30775785
23  3  16.114831628  -5.4750642   8.58762550
24  3  -0.309470950   7.0656088  10.07624289
25  3  11.225609780   4.2121241  16.59168866
26  3  -3.762529113   6.4369973  15.82362705
27  3  -5.103277731   0.9215625  18.20823042
28  3 -10.623165177  -5.2896293  33.13656839
29  3  -0.002517872   5.0861361  -0.01966699
30  3  -2.183752881  24.4644310  13.55572730
```

Comment: Could you show the desired output for your example? I'm not sure how you're choosing which element of vals to multiply by each room column.

Comment: I've added a snapshot of the desired output. Any element of vals can be used to multiply the columns for each ID, as long as it is a different element of vals for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem. You can use a new dataset of all id, value combinations to make sure you calculate each combination and merge on the Room values. Then use mutate to make new Room columns.

Also, in the future I'd recommend setting a seed when asking questions with random data as it's easier for someone to replicate your output.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
df<-data.frame(id=rep(1:10,each=10),
               Room1=rnorm(100,0.4,0.5),
               Room2=rnorm(100,0.3,0.5),
               Room3=rnorm(100,0.7,0.5))
vals <- sample(7:100, 10)
other_df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10),
                       val = rep(vals, 10))

df2 <- inner_join(other_df, df)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Room1 = Room1*val,
         Room2 = Room2*val,
         Room3 = Room3*val)
```